# JS and HTML select box with preselected values based on user first selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a WebApp using HTML, JS and Python and the idea is to have some select box where the user select the first one and based on that I pre-select the others on the backend.

The rule is the following:

- if user select A then Level 3
- if user select B then Level 0
- if user select C then show only Level 4 and Level 5

I started something like this:

```js
const DGSelect = document.getElementById('DG');
const STGSelect = document.getElementById('STG');

STGSelect.value = '';
DGSelect.value = '';

function preselectSTG() {
  const selectedDGValue = DGSelect.value;

  if (selectedDGValue === 'A') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 3';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'B') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 0';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'C') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 4';
  } else {
    STGSelect.value = '';
    DGSelect.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="DG">Decision Group:</label>
    <select name="DG" id="DG">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="STG">STGCD:</label>
    <select name="STG" id="STG">
      <option value="LVL 0">Level 0</option>
      <option value="LVL 3">Level 3</option>
      <option value="LVL 4">Level 4</option>
      <option value="LVL 5">Level 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need an event listener for the user changing `DG` that calls the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all in this select section

```
  <select name="DG" id="DG">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">C</option>
    </select>
```

i think you mean in the last option ,  `<option value="D">D</option>`

then you need to add **onchange option** in the **first select** section **(id="DG")**
like this

```
<select name="DG" id="DG" onchange="preselectSTG()">
     <option value="A">A</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

for **the second div** **(id="STG")** it should be like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="STG">STGCD:</label>
      <select name="STG" id="STG"></select>
    </div>
```

then for the **Java Script code** here is the code :
**JS**

```
    const DGSelect = document.getElementById("DG");
    const STGSelect = document.getElementById("STG");
    var op = document.createElement("option"); // creats a new option element
    STGSelect.disabled = true; // disable the second select
    
    function preselectSTG() {
      const selectedDGValue = DGSelect.value;
      STGSelect.disabled = false; // the disable is set to false
      if (selectedDGValue === "A") {
        STGSelect.innerHTML = ""; //clear all options in second Select
        op.textContent = "Level 3"; //the text between option tag
        op.value = "LVL 3"; // the value of option
        STGSelect.appendChild(op); // add the element to the select
      } else if (selectedDGValue === "B") {
        STGSelect.innerHTML = "";
        op.textContent = "Level 0";
        op.value = "LVL 0";
        STGSelect.appendChild(op);
      } else if (selectedDGValue === "C") {
        STGSelect.innerHTML = ""; 
        op.textContent = "Level 4"; // add the lvl 4
        op.value = "LVL 4";
        STGSelect.appendChild(op);
        var op2 = document.createElement("option");
        op2.textContent = "Level 5"; //add the lvl 5
        op2.value = "LVL 5";
        STGSelect.appendChild(op2);
      } else {
        STGSelect.innerHTML = "";
        op.textContent = "";
        op.value = "";
      }
```

**I highly suggest to look for createElement method , it is very useful and hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps,
I just placed an event listener to make it interactive with the element.

you write a comment below about what is missing and I will do my best to turn the code to work as required.

```js
const DGSelect = document.getElementById('DG');
const STGSelect = document.getElementById('STG');

STGSelect.value = '';
DGSelect.value = '';

DGSelect.addEventListener("change", preselectSTG)
function preselectSTG() {
  const selectedDGValue = DGSelect.value;

  if (selectedDGValue === 'A') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 3';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'B') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 0';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'C') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 4';
  } else {
    STGSelect.value = '';
    DGSelect.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="DG">Decision Group:</label>
    <select name="DG" id="DG">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">C</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="STG">STGCD:</label>
    <select name="STG" id="STG">
      <option value="LVL 0">Level 0</option>
      <option value="LVL 3">Level 3</option>
      <option value="LVL 4">Level 4</option>
      <option value="LVL 5">Level 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an event listener that calls the function.

Second, the function is missing the third case, hiding levels 4 and 5.

```js
const DGSelect = document.getElementById('DG');
const STGSelect = document.getElementById('STG');

STGSelect.value = '';
DGSelect.value = '';

DGSelect.addEventListener("change", preselectSTG);

function preselectSTG() {
  const selectedDGValue = DGSelect.value;
  // Preselect option from STG
  if (selectedDGValue === 'A') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 3';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'B') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 0';
  } else if (selectedDGValue === 'C') {
    STGSelect.value = 'LVL 4';
  } else {
    STGSelect.value = '';
    DGSelect.value = '';
  }
  // Hide unavailable options in STG
  if (selectedDGValue === 'C') {
    document.getElementById("STG0").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("STG3").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("STG0").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("STG3").style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="DG">Decision Group:</label>
    <select name="DG" id="DG">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="STG">STGCD:</label>
    <select name="STG" id="STG">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="LVL 0" id="STG0">Level 0</option>
      <option value="LVL 3" id="STG3">Level 3</option>
      <option value="LVL 4" id="STG4">Level 4</option>
      <option value="LVL 5" id="STG5">Level 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```